# How to put image in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Can you tell me how to do like below in JAVA SWING.

[image]

Comment: Is the image really _in_ the text field, or is a a label _next to_ the text field?

Comment: http://harryjoy.com/2012/07/14/jtextfield-with-image-inside-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a custom component.

Take a look at http://gmigdos.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/java-a-custom-jtextfield-for-searching/

Comment: While link only answers are allowed it is good idea to provide main content to answer in case link will change.

Answer (score 2):

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField() {  
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
                super.paintComponent(g);  
                int y = (getHeight() - image.getHeight())/2;  
                g.drawImage(image, x0, y, this);  
            }  
        };
```

Comment: thanks Nambi very much

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial. He does exactly what you're trying to do:
http://harryjoy.me/2012/07/14/jtextfield-with-image-inside-it/